# webstorm bug? project pane missing, did i bump a hotkey?

Tags: ide, webstorm

I.T. gave me an upgrade to V5 and I can't see my directory listing.
Maybe I bumped a hotkey i don;t know about?
You can see a screengrab here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23768853/help.jpg

I'm combing thru all the preferences but so far nothing, anyone know how to make it come back?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed !
I.T.  re-copied the application into the application folder and webstorm is working normally again.
Surprising to think that the application can run even after a corrupt install.